# Read packets in Wireshark

Tags: networking, wireshark

[image: bitcoin-wireshark]

INV message hex dump shared on https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/p2p_networking.html#inv has information about transactions that is human readable but I don't see anything similar in INV or GETDATA or TX when capturing packets for 2 regtest Bitcoin nodes running locally.

Maybe the format has changed or its hashed. Or I am missing something basic in Wireshark which can be helpful in reading captured packets?

Answer (score 0):

INV message has WTXID but in reverse.

```
INV: f84ef7024f4a9d91605a5c1eae28664391ce0c8dc29d2fb396af24fe5c3a6499

WTXID: 99643a5cfe24af96b32f9dc28d0cce91436628ae1e5c5a60919d4a4f02f74ef8
```

Comment: That doesn't look reverse, but like it was encoded in big-endian but read as little-endian or vice versa.

Comment: The way I reversed one of the INV and interpret this: last 2 characters in INV are `99`, print them. Next two characters from end are `64`, print them and so on. So you get 9964.. in WTXID